# Show that $f^{(n)} (0) = 0,$ for all $n \geq 1.$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, smooth-functions

> Define a function $f : \mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ by $$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/x^2}&x\neq 0\\
> 0&x=0
> \end{cases}$$
>
> Show that $f^{(n)} (0) = 0,$ for all $n \geq 1.$

I can prove that $f'(0) = f''(0) = 0.$ But for larger $n$ how do I show that? I think we have to use induction on $n.$ But I can't able to show that $f^{(n+1)} (0) = 0$ whenever $f^{(n)} (0) = 0.$ I am thinking about applying [Leibnitz rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) here. Is there any clever way to show that?

Some suggestion will be boon for me at this stage. Thanks!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/257579/42969

Comment: @Martin R the question you linked has no well accepted answer. Then how can my question be closed in reference to the linked post?

Comment: @Martin R can you please give me some reference?

Comment: The linked question has answers with 4 and 9 upvotes, I wouldn't call that “not well accepted.” Here is another Q&A about the same problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/332142/42969.

Comment: @Martin R I mean it has not been accepted by the OP. Isn't it? That means the fact is not entirely clear to him/her.

Comment: Some people forget to accept an answer, or just don't bother, that is not necessarily an indicator for the correctness of an answer. Do *you* understand the (at least four) answers? If not, then you can either leave a comment and ask for clarification, or update your question with what you understand and what not.

Comment: @Fanatics Not every asker accepts answers to all their questions. That's just a reality we live with here. Whether an answer has been accepted is not really a measure of how good an answer is, because it's only the judgement of a single person, if they even bothered to judge. The fact that 9 different people decided was worth an upvote is generally a much better sign of quality than a green checkmark, or the lack of it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that $\lim_{x\to 0}F(x)e^{-1/x^2} = 0$ for all $F\in \mathbb R(X)$ (rational fractions in $X$). Then use induction.